# How do I use texture on a sphere in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, textures

I've downloaded a sphere example from: http://aerotwist.com/lab/getting-started-with-three-js/ and I can see the nice red sphere. I'd like to use a texture on it. I've tried this:

```
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("ball-texture.jpg");
texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;
texture.repeat.set( 125, 125 );
texture.offset.set( 15, 15 );
texture.needsUpdate = true;
var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.Sphere(radius, segments, rings),sphereMaterial);
```

but I can't see anything, all is black. Does anyone have a working example for sphere texture?

Comment: This is a total guess, since I know *nothing* about this, but if you've changed the material from a flat color to a texture, you may need to add a light source?  It may be that a constant color shader doesn't require one, while a textured object would.

Answer (score 3):

You might have two problems.

First, try loading it like this:

```
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('ball-texture.jpg', {}, function() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
});

texture.needsUpdate = true;
```

Make sure that the texture size is a power of two (512x512px for IE).

Comment: Postponing the rendering until the image has loaded worked for me - thanks!

Comment: @poshaughnessy How did you remove the vacant (blank white ) spaces that come when the texture is repeated ?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Firefox? This could be a problem in your browser. Firefox uses some kind of cross-site-blocker for textures. The result is black instead. Take a look at this site for more info: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/06/cross-domain-webgl-textures-disabled-in-firefox-5/

Comment: Seems like the current version of Chrome has the same "problem". It is actually a security issue: http://blog.chromium.org/2011/07/using-cross-domain-images-in-webgl-and.html

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a rendering loop, or did you render the scene just once?

You need to have a rendering loop so that when the THREE.ImageUtils loads the image and updates the texture, you re-render the scene with the now updated texture.

All the three.js examples seem to rely on this technique. I.e., Fire off several async operations involving a fetch of a remote resource, start rendering loop, let scene be updated as remote resources arrive.

IMHO this is Three.js's biggest gotcha for Javascript newbs (like me) who are not familiar with how async operations work.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, but if you are loading the html as a file (i.e. locally not a webserver), many browsers (chrome for e.g.) will not allow you to load images in the standard three.js way as it is a security violation.